# What is the series being used to find the approximation to Pi here

Tags: pi

I came across some (very) old COBOL code to calculate an approximation to Pi that piqued my interest as converged much more quickly than the Leibniz formula producing a result accurate to 14 decimal places after just 21 iterations.

However COBOL isn't the easiest language to follow when to comes to more complicated mathematical expressions so to make it easier to see what was going on I translated it to Python...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

_sum = 0.5
_delta = 0.5
_next = 1
_count = 0

while _delta > _error:
    _count += 1
    _delta = (_delta * (_next * _next)) / (4 * (_next + 1) * (_next + 2))
    _sum = _sum + _delta
    print('%.4d ' % _count +'%.14f' % (_sum * 6) + ' %.15f' % _delta)
    _next = _next + 2

# Produces pi = 3.14159265358979 after just 21 iterations... 
print('Pi = %.14f' % (_sum * 6) + ' after %d iterations' % _count)
```

However I still couldn't quite work out what method of approximation is being used.  It obviously isn't the [Leibniz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80) and though I think it is based another one of the [Madhava series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madhava_series) I can't see how the code above is is derived by substituting q = 1/sqrt(3) (and therefore π / 6) in Madhava's expansion for arctan().

(Possibly because it is late and it has been a long long time since I last did this sort of thing).

Just out of interest can anyone identify what the function is that results in the expansion used in the code above when it is used to sum successive terms?

Thank you.